# Size of LinkedList node

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, linked-list

The `int` size is `4` byte and when running this program, getting output as `16`.
May I know the reason why the output is `16`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

int main()
{
    printf( "%d\n", sizeof(list) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because padding paired with pointer size being equal to 8 on your machine. For sure there exist a duplicate of this question

Answer (score 1):

The type of each member of the structure usually has a default alignment, meaning that it will, unless otherwise requested by the programmer, be aligned on a pre-determined boundary.

As you mentioned that the size of `int` is `4` and size of pointer on your system architecture will be `8`. Hence, to align the `next` pointer of structure `list` the compiler must be padding the structure with `4` bytes.

Some compilers supports the warning flag `-Wpadded`, which generates helpful warnings about structure padding, and one of them is `gcc` compiler. I have added couple of `printf` in your code to make the things clear:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list;

int main()
{
    list l;
    printf( "Size of struct list member data: %zu\n", sizeof(l.data) );
    printf( "Size of struct list member next: %zu\n", sizeof(l.next) );
    printf( "Size of struct list: %zu\n", sizeof(list) );
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code with `-Wpadded` flag, getting the warning message:

```
# gcc -Wpadded prg.c
p.c:5:18: warning: padding struct 'struct list' with 4 bytes to align 'next' [-Wpadded]
    struct list *next;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

The padding warning message from compiler is self explanatory.
Following is the output when running it:

```
#./a.out
Size of struct list member data: 4
Size of struct list member next: 8
Size of struct list: 16
```

Also, the type of the result of `sizeof` operator is `size_t`. You should use `%zu` format specifier instead of `%d`.